# how to create a pop up menu which is linked with listbox in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, popupmenu

I'm trying to create a listbox in which pressing 'Enter key' AKA `<Return>` will
pop up a menu in front of the row selected, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksfPu.png)
I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63725428/popup-menu-on-button-click-in-tkinter) example but it seems that menu pops up only where the mouse is located 

Is what I'm asking even possible to do? If so, how can I get the x,y locations of any row in the listbox?

sadly, I couldn't even provide a pseudo code to explain further because I have no idea what it would even look like, so please pardon my lack of clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `curselection` method of the listbox will return a list of selected items. The `bbox` method of the listbox will give the coordinates of an item relative to the listbox itself. You can use `winfo_rootx` and `winfo_rooty` to get the absolute coordinates of the listbox on the screen. You can use all of this information to place the menu near the selected item.

For example:

```
def show_popup(event):
    selection = event.widget.curselection()
    if selection:
        item = selection[0]
        rootx = event.widget.winfo_rootx()
        rooty = event.widget.winfo_rooty()
        itemx, itemy, itemwidth, itemheight = event.widget.bbox(item)
        popup_menu.tk_popup(rootx+event.widget.winfo_width()-10, rooty+itemy+10)
```

Comment: thank you so much, every time I have a tkinter problem your answers always seem to help out, may I know where you learned tkinter from? I mean it must be from years of experience but have you ever considered creating your own website to pass on the knowledge?

Comment: I started working with tcl/tk to create commercial apps back in the mid-90's. tkinter is just a wrapper around tcl/tk. I learned tkinter by answering questions on this site, which forced me to apply my knowledge of tk in python.